# web3js: web3.eth.defaultAccount method?

Tags: web3js, testrpc

:) I am new to Ethereum technology. I am studying the web3js JavaScript library from the official [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3) and I don't understand the `web3.eth.defaultAccount`. What is this for? Why I have to use it in my web application? For example, this code:

```
web3Istance.eth.defaultAccount = web3Istance.eth.accounts[0];
```

I am using testrpc for testing my Dapp locally. So in this case I set the first account to be the default one. But why I do have to set the default account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaultAccount` is used as the default `from` field when you send a transaction. That is, if you send a transaction and do not specify the `from` field, the value of `web3.eth.defaultAccount` will be used, if previously set. In case of no `from` as well as no `defaultAccount`, an error occurs.